# HTTP Status 404 - Not Found on jsp

Tags: javascript, java, jquery, html, jsp

When I run with netbeans it's always open HTTP Status 404 - Not Found on my browser. I try to solve that but nothing changes. Please help me. Here is my code:

calendar.jsp

```html
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<link href='css/fullcalendar.css' rel='stylesheet' />
<script src='js/jquery-1.9.1.min.js'></script>
<script src='js/jquery-ui-1.10.2.custom.min.js'></script>
<script src='js/fullcalendar.min.js'></script>
<script>

 $(document).ready(function() {
  var date = new Date();
  var d = date.getDate();
  var m = date.getMonth();
  var y = date.getFullYear();

  var calendar = $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
   editable: true,
   header: {
    left: 'prev,next today',
    center: 'title',
    right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay'
   },

   events: "event.jsp",

   // Convert the allDay from string to boolean
   eventRender: function(event, element, view) {
    if (event.allDay === 'true') {
     event.allDay = true;
    } else {
     event.allDay = false;
    }
   },
   selectable: true,
   selectHelper: true,
   select: function(start, end, allDay) {
   var title = prompt('Event Title:');
   var url = prompt('Type Event url, if exits:');
   if (title) {
   var start = $.fullCalendar.formatDate(start, "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
   var end = $.fullCalendar.formatDate(end, "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
   $.ajax({
   url: 'add_event.jsp',
   data: 'title='+ title+'&start='+ start +'&end='+ end +'&url='+ url ,
   type: "POST",
   success: function(json) {
   alert('Added Successfully');
   }
   });
   calendar.fullCalendar('renderEvent',
   {
   title: title,
   start: start,
   end: end,
   allDay: allDay
   },
   true // make the event "stick"
   );
   }
   calendar.fullCalendar('unselect');
   },

   editable: true,
   eventDrop: function(event, delta) {
   var start = $.fullCalendar.formatDate(event.start, "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
   var end = $.fullCalendar.formatDate(event.end, "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
   $.ajax({
   url: 'update_event.jsp',
   data: 'title='+ event.title+'&start='+ start +'&end='+ end +'&id='+ event.id ,
   type: "POST",
   success: function(json) {
    alert("Updated Successfully");
   }
   });
   },
   eventResize: function(event) {
   var start = $.fullCalendar.formatDate(event.start, "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
   var end = $.fullCalendar.formatDate(event.end, "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
   $.ajax({
    url: 'update_event.jsp',
    data: 'title='+ event.title+'&start='+ start +'&end='+ end +'&id='+ event.id ,
    type: "POST",
    success: function(json) {
     alert("Updated Successfully");
    }
   });

}

  });

 });

</script>
<style>

 body {
  margin-top: 40px;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-family: "Lucida Grande",Helvetica,Arial,Verdana,sans-serif;

  }


 #calendar {
  width: 900px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  }

</style>
</head>
<body>
<div id='calendar'></div>
</body>
</html>
```

event.jsp

```html
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<%@ page import="java.sql.*"%>

 <%  
    Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
    Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/fullcalendar",
            "root", "");
    Statement st = con.createStatement();
    ResultSet rs;
    rs = st.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM evenement ORDER BY id");

%>
```

add_event.jsp

```html
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<%@ page import="java.sql.*"%>

 <%
    String start = request.getParameter("start");    
    String end = request.getParameter("end");
    String title = request.getParameter("title");
    String url = request.getParameter("url");

    Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
    Connection con = java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/fullcalendar",
            "root", "");
    Statement st = con.createStatement();
    ResultSet rs;
    rs = st.executeQuery("INSERT INTO evenement (title, start, end, url) "
            + "values ('" + title + "','" + start + "','" + end + "','" + url + "')");

%>
```

update_event.jsp

```html
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<%@ page import="java.sql.*"%>
<%
 String start = request.getParameter("start");    
    String end = request.getParameter("end");
    String title = request.getParameter("title");
    String url = request.getParameter("url");

    Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
    Connection con = java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/fullcalendar",
            "root", "");
    Statement st = con.createStatement();
    ResultSet rs;
    rs = st.executeQuery("UPDATE evenement set ('" + title + "','" + start + "','" + end + "','" + url + "')");

%>
```

Comment: This seems like a pretty abstract approach... why are you using all these jsp's?  Are you familiar with MVC structure?  I'm no security expert, but your approach seems like it would be vulnerable to code injection.

Comment: i am poor programming, my first time to use jsp. i learn it from internet. can u give link or reference for learn how better make web application use java ? i dont undestand what is MVC structure. i know my application will be vulnerable to code injection. this code just my homework because i student.

Comment: Then your best resource would be your professor.  You can google "Java MVC" to get an idea of how it works.

Answer (score 0):

Pardon me if this sounds elementary, but a 404 error means that something that is being referred to is not there. I would go through your links and ensure everything has been uploaded to where it is being hosted.